# What does setting "open" on the <details> tag actually do, in CSS terms?

Tags: css, html, accessibility

I'm upgrading my site to use the `<details>` tag, for accessibility purposes.

My question is this. When the "open" attribute is set on the `<details>` tag, as below:

```
<details open>  
    <summary>more info</summary>  
    <ul>        
        <li>blah</li>        
    </ul>
</details>
```

is there anything different in CSS terms about the `<ul>` tag? It seems to have `display: block` set whether it's visible or not.

I'm trying to write front-end tests to check that the `<ul>` becomes visible when the element is clicked, and I'm not sure how to do this without something actually being different in CSS.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6x2Kc/

Comment: I wouldn't use this element yet as it only seems to be supported in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I want to, for accessibility reasons. I'm using a shim to support older browsers: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-details-jquery

Answer (score 4):

In terms of how to detect visibility, Mathijs Flietstra's answer seems to fit the bill.

On the broader matter of what the CSS is actually doing, the HTML5 spec has something to say here:http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#the-details-element-0

It says:

> ... the [details] element is expected to render as a 'block' box with its 'padding-left' property set to '40px' for left-to-right elements (LTR-specific) and with its 'padding-right' property set to '40px' for right-to-left elements. The element's shadow tree is expected to take the element's first child summary element, if any, and place it in a first 'block' box container, and then take the element's remaining descendants, if any, and place them in a second 'block' box container.
>
> The first container is expected to contain at least one line box, and that line box is expected to contain a disclosure widget (typically a triangle), horizontally positioned within the left padding of the details element. That widget is expected to allow the user to request that the details be shown or hidden.
>
> The second container is expected to have its 'overflow' property set to 'hidden'. When the details element does not have an open attribute, this second container is expected to be removed from the rendering.

In other words, the content of the details element other the summary element is put into an *anonymous* block box. (This is a bit similar to how if you make an element `display:table-cell` then it will be wrapped in anonymous boxes for table-row, table-row-group and table.) It is this anonymous box (and thereby its contents) that is hidden or shown, which is why you can't see the CSS specified values change for any element that you select, only the computed values.

A word of warning though. We don't have many implementations of the details element yet, and the spec text above doesn't require browsers to do it like that, it only says "expected to", so the other browsers may choose to achieve the effect by other means. We can only wait to find out.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, the computed values of the `ul`'s `height` and `width` properties change to `auto` when `details` is closed. Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6x2Kc/13/)</kbd> which alerts the `ul`'s height when you click on `details`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `open` attribute of a `<details>` element determines whether the height of the content will be the natural height, or zero. If `open` is present, the height will be the content's normal height, if the attribute is absent, or the content is toggled closed, the height is zero. Here's a quick **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6x2Kc/12/)**.